# Using an STL List of a Struct in C++

Tags: c++, list, stl, struct

I know I'm probably doing something unforgivably stupid here, but for some reason my code won't compile and I'm not sure why.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <list> 

//A queue for the working set
//x,y co-ords of the square, path length so far 
struct square {
 int x;
 int y; 
 int path_length;
} square; 

list<square> workingset;
```

I have other code which appears to create a list in exactly the same way -

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>   //List class library 
#include <algorithm> //STL algorithms class library (find) 

using namespace std;

list<int> numberlist; //Creates my list
```

And the problem doesn't appear to be because of the struct, as I have tried making a list of ints too, and it won't work either.

The errors I am getting are -

syntax error : missing ';' before '<'  and  missing type specifier - int assumed.

(Both on the line in which I am trying to declare a list)

So what incredibly stupid thing am I missing here? :3

Comment: Use std::list to declare a list.

Comment: Can anybody help me?
[Modify an attribute element from a list of STL of a structure in C ++][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30798787/4959934

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `list` class is defined in the `std` namespace, so you have to either do this:

```
std::list<square> workingset;
```

Or this

```
using namespace std;
list<square> workingset;
```

Answer (score 2):

Put `std::` in front of the `list<square> workingset;`

---

you could just include `using namespace std;`, but it's not that good idea, if this is in a header file.

Comment: Aye, it's a teeny-tiny program so using namespace std; should be fine :) Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can't use `square` as the name of the struct as well as the name of a variable.

The following code should fail to compile:

```
struct square {
 int x;
 int y; 
 int path_length;
} square; 

square getSquare
{
   return square();
}
```

Try this instead:

```
struct square {
 int x;
 int y; 
 int path_length;
} aSquare; 

square getSquare
{
   return square();
}
```